# Mattermost Bitnami AWS AMI: Issues with implementing letsencrypt SSL for nginx on AWS but can’t figure out how to make it work

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, bitnami, mattermost

Even if the files are there, the nginx cannot run properly.

I followed this tutorial step by step: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/

I also looked into these.
https://community.bitnami.com/t/trouble-installing-new-certificates/64634?source_topic_id=70529

https://community.bitnami.com/t/unable-to-install-ssl-certificate/57650?source_topic_id=70529

Input:
sudo ln -s /etc/lego/certificates/blah.crt /opt/bitnami/apps/mattermost/conf/certs/server.crt
sudo ln -s /etc/lego/certificates/blah.key /opt/bitnami/apps/mattermost/conf/certs/server.key
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart nginx

Result:
Unmonitored nginx
/opt/bitnami/nginx/scripts/ctl.sh : Nginx stopped
nginx: [warn] the "ssl" directive is deprecated, use the "listen ... ssl" directive instead in /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/mattermost.conf:17
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/opt/bitnami/apps/mattermost/conf/certs/server.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/opt/bitnami/apps/mattermost/conf/certs/server.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
/opt/bitnami/nginx/scripts/ctl.sh: 77: [: Illegal number: 
/opt/bitnami/nginx/scripts/ctl.sh : Nginx could not be started
Monitored nginx

I want to see my website and have it run with HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

sudo ln -sf /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates/YOUR_DOMAIN.crt /opt/bitnami/apps/mattermost/conf/certs/server.crt
sudo ln -sf /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates/YOUR_DOMAIN.key /opt/bitnami/apps/mattermost/conf/certs/server.key
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart nginx